# Custom permalink structure for posts in certain categories

Tags: customization, permalinks

As the title says, I want to create a different permalink structure for posts belonging to a certain category, in my case, the name is "ICO". I've found this piece of code on StackExchange, but it doesn't really do anything for me, contrary to the OPs feedback.

The code is:

```
//Rewrite URLs for "ICO" category
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );

function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
// Get the category for the post
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "ICO" ) {
    $cat_name = strtolower($category[0]->cat_name);
    $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/'. $cat_name . '/' . $post->post_name .'/' ) );
}
return $permalink;
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules' );
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
add_rewrite_rule(
    'ico/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$',
    'index.php?category_name=ico&name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
    'top' // The rule position; either 'top' or 'bottom' (default).
);
}
```

All posts from that category, present on the homepage do not have their URL changed, the default URL structure is the same www.site.com/post_name/

However, I noticed that on some widgets, in a list with posts from that category, some of the posts have their URL changed, some do not. There isn't any difference between them, they have the same categories. Even if I go on that URL /ico/post_name/ it works and if I delete /ico/ and go on the default permalink structure, it works as well, making it a duplicate URL for the same post.

What have I done wrong?

Edit: I also tried this piece of code, same effect, not working

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    // Get the categories for the post
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID); 
    if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->cat_name == "ICO" ) {
        $cat_name = strtolower($category[0]->cat_name);
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/'. $cat_name . '/' . $post->post_name .'/' ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
function custom_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    // This rule will will match the post id in %postname%-%post_id% struture
    $new_rules['ico/^([^/]*)/?'] = 'index.php?p=$matches[1]';
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
}
```

Comment: did you flush your rewrite rules afterwards? resaved a post that is inside that specific category..?

Comment: actually I did, nothing happed. Moreover, the posts that have the url changed with the /ico/ category, when I click on them, instead of taking me to the post page, displays the featured image attached to that post.

Comment: as resaving, didn't think of doing that..I'll do that now, I thought this rule works as changing the permalinks from WP directly, you don't need to resave all posts.

Comment: I resaved a bunch of articles, did a permalink save, added flush_rewrite_rules(); to the function in function.php...nothing works. I'm clearly missing something or there's something wrong with the code.

Comment: so, you paste your code and edit your post yadayada all works fine, when you hit save, the permalink below the title is all good, has ico inside, the issue comes with the rewrite. correct?

Comment: The issue is with rewrite, when I paste this function, every widget or post list present on the site doesn't have the URL changed to the /ico/ one. There are however, in those lists, some articles that have /ico/ inside, it's completely random, I'm not sure why. I've checked all these articles, they don't have anything different. It's worth noting that each article has it's main category "ICO" then at least 1 subcategory which has ICO parent.

Comment: One more thing, it seems that if I try to create another post from the ICO category, in admin, it automatically ads /ico/ to the permalink.

Comment: ok kool, that is what you want, right?! looks like the first bit of your code is running, that was my question.. so for the rewirte, please try this `add_rewrite_rule('ico/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]', 'top');
`

Comment: I want the permalink structure to be modified to ALL posts, even the already written ones. I can't change the permalink structure of those, even if I edit the permalink under the title, can't add /ico/ it just appends /ico-name/

Comment: I'm starting to believe that having 2 or more categories assigned to each post may break this code. The main category, ICO, has 3 subcategories and every post from ICO has at least 1 other subcategory. Not sure if this is the problem, but..

Comment: did you try my rewrite? and regarding your guessing/subcategory: inside `custom_permalink` you only check, if the very first category is ico.. why not make a loop through all categories?

Comment: I did, no effect. What do you mean by making a loop through all categories? care to give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution to search through all categories, not only the first one.

```
add_filter('post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 2);
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post ) {
    // Get the categories for the post
    $categories = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'category'); 
    if (!empty($categories)) {
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($category->cat_name == "ICO") {
                $cat_name = strtolower($category->cat_name);
                $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/' . $cat_name . '/' . $post->post_name . '/' ) );
                break; //we found ico, so exit foreach immediately
            }
        }
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

Comment: Tried it now, doesn't do anything, not even the "failed" rewrite the first iteration did. I tried using both custom rewrite rules, the original and the one you specified after, same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the main functionn to this:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );

function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
// Get the category for the post
$category = get_the_category($post->ID);
$cat_id = get_cat_ID ( $category );
if (  !empty($category) && has_category('ICO',$post->ID) ) {
    $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/ico/' . $post->post_name .'/' ) );
}
return $permalink;
}
```

This changes the URL correctly to all the posts from the ICO category. However, if I go to any of these articles, it returns a 404, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Ok, rushing this, I forgot to regenerate permalinks and now it works. However, one problem still remains, if I delete the /ico/ portion of the URL, the link works aswell, pointing to the same page. Not sure how to fix this.